# Pass POST data to FormWizard

Tags: django, django-formwizard

Is it possible to pass POST data to the first step of a FormWizard?

I've got quite a lot of data to pass in to the wizard so I don't want to use url kwargs but I can't seem to figure out how to POST to it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried it, but if it's a lot of data, I think I would go about this by saving the POST data into the session. This way you can leave it there until you need it. I found an example of this at the bottom of this post:

[Inserting initial data into a SessionWizardView form field either from a URL pattern or post data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825273/inserting-initial-data-into-a-sessionwizardview-form-field-either-from-a-url-pat)

Comment: I thought that might be the case. I've found another way around this issue in my case but I'm sure this is the only real way to do it if needed. Thanks.